# Relationship Issue with CRM 2016 Entities

Tags: crm, entity-relationship, dynamics-crm-2016

consider following scenario. I have 4 entities as follows:

Contact
lender
Financial Statement
Loan

now, this four entities have relation to each other as follows:
Contact and Financial statement - 1:N Referential
Lender and financial Statement - 1:N Referential
contact And Loan - 1:N Referential
Lender And Loan - 1:N Referential
Loan and Financial statement - 1:N Referential

on loan entity, Go to 1:N relationship, there select loan and financial statement relationship,

Now on Left Pane we are having mapping Option,
there I have added new mapping between primary contact field of loan (this field is because of contact And Loan - 1:N Referential relationship) and primary contact field of financial statement (this field is because of contact And Financial statement - 1:N Referential relationship).

also added another mapping for loan and financial statement relationship.
I have added new mapping between lender_id field of loan (this field is because of Lender  And Loan - 1:N Referential relationship) and lender_id field of financial statement (this field is because of Lender And Financial statement - 1:N Referential relationship).

i have publish this customization ,working fine on source environment,then i exported package from source environment with all these changes included,and import it on target environment,

this package imported successfully with warning on target environment,when i checked this above describe relationship of primary contact and lender_id in mapping part, it was missing there and I checked logs for warning, then it was showing:

> Cannot map attribute 'new_lenderid' on entity 'new_loan' to attribute >'new_lender' on entity 'new_financialstatement'. Either an attribute is not >mappable, or attributes are of different types, or the size of the target >attribute is smaller than the size of the source attribute
>
> Cannot map attribute 'new_primarycontact' on entity 'new_loan' to attribute >'new_primarycontact' on entity 'new_financialstatement'. Either an attribute is >not mappable, or attributes are of different types, or the size of the target >attribute is smaller than the size of the source attribute.

please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Sounds like one of the truckload of issues that solutions have in 2016. Have you tried mapping the attributes manually (and did you succeed) ?

Comment: After  mapping attributes Manually this issue resolved ,but every time I need do this when import package on new environment. That's why looking for other solution.